# Income Tax - Net amount payable after filing the retrn for year 2013-14

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india

I already file returns for year 2013-14, after e - verification  I got intimation that I need to pay Rupees 570/-, along with that ITNS 280 also attached.

How can I pay the pending amount. Can be paid online or do I have to go bank / income tax office.

Answer (score 1):

You can pay the taxes online. Visit the [Income Tax Site](https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp). Select the Right Challan ITNS280. Select 0021, then select 400 [This should be mentioned in your ITNS] Ensure you are paying the tax against the notice.

After you pay the tax, note the details. You would need to file a revised return for the same year. When filing revised returns, ensure that you select the right reason for revision based on the notice.